# How to handle delete booking webtours in jmeter?

Tags: scripting, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

How to handle the remove flight booking in webtours? It came to my mind that if I wanna run the test with 3 virtual users and how they supposed to delete the booking if the information down here (refer below) are unique for each virtual user? Does any of these variables below need to be parameterized or need to apply correlation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple flight id to be deleted, we can create a CSV file having those ids
and use a while loop controller to delete each of them.

You may refer -

1. https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG
2. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter

As you said, it will differ for a different user, you can store each value from the response of each user(extract value using regex) and pass them in delete call.

reference link - https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "webtours" is, however there is one "golden" rule: each and every parameter which is dynamic needs to be correlated.

If you don't have any idea regarding which ones are dynamic - record the same action one more time using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and compare the generated requests, parameter values (or even names) which differ needs to be correlated.

Another approach is to inspect the previous response(s) using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and look if the data is present there

Check out [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) article for more information and example implementation